How to manage a single transaction across multiple databases using existing transaction managers in Spring?
I am working on a Spring-based application where I have two separate Platform Transaction Manager:

One transaction manager for handling transactions on Database A (JpaTranscationManager).
Another transaction manager for handling transactions on Database B (JpaTranscationManager).

Both databases are necessary for the operation of my application. However, I need to perform some operations that require a single transaction encompassing both databases. The challenge is that I cannot modify the existing transaction managers.
Is there a way to orchestrate a single global transaction in Spring that includes both these databases, ensuring atomicity and consistency, without altering the existing transaction managers?
Any pointers or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Here are some details about my current setup:

Spring Boot version: [3.1.11]
Database : [MySQL DB]
Current Transaction Managers: [JpaTranscationManager]



I tried using one of the transcation manager as global transcation but it didnt rolled back for operations on other DB.
@Service
public class TableService {
    @Autowired
    private Table1Repository table1Repository;

    @Autowired
    private Table2Repository table2Repository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_1)
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_2)
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2;

    @Transactional(transactionManager = Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_1, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void save() {
        saveTable1(createtable1());
        saveTable2(createtable2());
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager = Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_1, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveTable1(Table1 table1) {
        table1Repository.save(table1);
    }

    @Transactional(transactionManager = Constants.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_2, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void saveTable2(Table2 table2) {
        table2Repository.save(table2);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

I want the save() method to handle both saveTable1 and saveTable2 as a single transaction. Currently, if I use transactionManager1 and an exception occurs, only saveTable1 is rolled back. I need both actions to roll back together, without modifying the existing transaction managers.
The complete code can be found at
https://github.com/srk830/transactions-poc.git
Is there a way to achieve this in Spring while keeping the current transaction managers unchanged?
